# How to prevent text from moving when I move the mouse after mousedown?

Tags: jquery, html, css, dialog

I am trying to write a movable dialog but there is a problem. Sometimes when I want to move the dialog by moving somewhere above the dialog, instead of the dialog itself, the title text is moving, as show below:
[image]

**CSS** for the title text:

```
.arg-dialog-title{
    height: 20px;
    font-size: x-large;
    padding: 10px 30px 15px 30px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: transparent;
    box-sizing: initial;
    font-weight: bold;
    outline: none;
    line-height: 1;
    border:0;
    user-drag: none; 
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
     text-decoration: none;
}
```

You can find all the codes and styles in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5f6v5rgq/).

How can I prevent this action from occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the following style to your title:

```
user-drag: none; 
user-select: none;
```

Also, make it listen to the `mousemove` event and adjust the position of the dialogue.

Comment: and browser(chrome) doesn't support

Answer (score 0):

Add the following script inside your `$(document).ready()` event.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].onselectstart = function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass("arg-dialog-title") || 
       (e.target).hasClass("arg-dialog-close-button")) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  };
```

What it does is disabled select for the HTML element with `class = "arg-dialog-title"` and `class = "arg-dialog-close-button"`. Disabling selecting on the title will also prevent dragging.

What you may have not noticed, however, is that if you drag the close button the button itself along with the title will be selected and therefore dragged. That's way I also added the close button's class.

I also updated your fiddle. Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5f6v5rgq/3/).

---

If you don't want the users to select anything on your website, except text in inputs or textareas then use this script:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].onselectstart = function(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName != "INPUT" && e.target.nodeName != "TEXTAREA") {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};
```